# AS3: Changes to XML file not taking effect

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Flash web application for a client. The application has two XML configuration files that are loaded from the server when users browse to the page.

According to the client, edits to one of the files stop taking effect after he has opened the page that has the Flash app. What he is describing (with placeholder names for simplicity):

1. He creates a folder "abc" on the server and places document.swf, config1.xml, and config2.xml in the folder.
2. He changes *'title'* in config1.xml to "new title" and saves it
3. He changes *'volume'* in config2.xml to 10 and saves it
4. He navigates to server.com/folder/documentwrapper.html and the SWF appears with the previous changes
5. He changes *'title'* in config1.xml to "newer title" and saves it
6. He changes *'volume'* in config2.xml to 0 and saves it
7. He navigates to server.com/folder/documentwrapper.html in any browser, and the SWF appears with change 6 but not change 5. Any more changes to config1.xml never appear when running the SWF

Both config1.xml and config2.xml are loaded in identical fashion by the same XML loader class. I cannot think of any rational explanation for the behavior he is experiencing. Unfortunately I don't have access to his test server so I can't easily test this myself.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just some server or client caching?

Comment: He claims he has cleared his cache and even tried it in a different browser. Why and how would the server cache one XML file but not the other?

Comment: I don't know, does seem odd.  Have they tried accessing the xml directly in their browser to see if its the same issue? (eg take flash out of the picture).   You can test server cache by loading in the url with random query string parameters.  eg  `new UrlRequest("mypathToXml.xml?" + (new Date()).time);`

Comment: if the assessment is correct then it is not a cache issue and could be: 1. a path issue, 2: a loader logic issue, 3: a xml edit issue.

Comment: I'll ask him, LDMS.

@BotMaster, it shouldn't be 2 or 3, since both XMLs are loaded the same way, and if he made a bad edit the XML should load improperly or cause a crash rather than somehow loading a previous version.